# redirect all browsers except webkit

Tags: php, jquery, apache

How does one redirect all browsers, other than webkit, to a specific URL?

I'm looking into Apache/Htaccess, jQuery/Javascript, etc., but I haven't found much, other than this thing for IE:

```
 <!--[if IE]>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location = "http://www.site.net/classic/";
   </script>
 <![endif]-->
```

In other words, how would one host a webkit-only website?

Comment: Sure, a PHP solution would be fine as well.

Comment: I hope you're not developing one version of your site for webkit browsers, and another for everyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `php` approach you could use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` variable to determinate which engine your user browser is using and then simply displaying the pages to the one with `webkit` engines, like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php   

    $navigator_user_agent = ' ' . strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    if (strpos($navigator_user_agent, "webkit")) { 
?>

//Your page goes here

<?php
    } else {

        header('Location: www.example.com/get-webkit'); //redirects user to the given location
    }
?>
```

Even doing the above, you can't be 100% sure about what browser are visiting your site since there are tools to modify how the browser are introduced to your server, including even cUrl based robots that can simply change it's user-agent variables.

Comment: Thanks.. So I would put the "if" part at the top of my index.php, then all of my site's scripts, html, css, etc., and then way down at the bottom I put in the "else" part?

Comment: Yes, your entire page goes where the comment is, including the `</html>` close tag.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. One more thing: Instead of telling them to get webkit, how do I php redirect them to www.site.com/non-webkit-loser/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is jquery solution:

```
  if (!$.browser.webkit) {
        window.location = "http://www.site.net/classic/";
   }
```

Comment: location.replace is better IMO

Comment: And then any browser such a lynx or links would be able to see the page. In fact every browser with javascript disable would see his page

Comment: No one said it was secure, just possible. Perhaps it is just to help the visitor. Op asked for a jquery example and got one. No need to down vote

Comment: (I don't know who downvoted it, seems kinda harsh.) It's like the exact opposite of what I need, but interesting nonetheless. "IF browser NOT webkit, go away" is really what I need though.

Comment: @mplungjan: Thanks for location.replace suggestion. The OP asked for JS/Jquery solution and I gave him one. I'm not saying it is perfect!